# Remove all special chars, but not non-Latin characters

Tags: php, regex, non-latin

I'm using this PHP function for SEO urls. It's working fine with Latin words, but my urls are on Cyrillic. This regex - `/[^a-z0-9_\s-]/` is not working with Cyrillic chars, please help me to make it works with non-Latin chars.

```
function seoUrl($string) {
    // Lower case everything
    $string = strtolower($string);
    // Make alphanumeric (removes all other characters)
    $string = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9_\s-]/', '', $string);
    // Clean up multiple dashes or whitespaces
    $string = preg_replace('/[\s-]+/', ' ', $string);
    // Convert whitespaces and underscore to dash
    $string = preg_replace('/[\s_]/', '-', $string);
    return $string;
}
```

Comment: Range: `U+0400–U+04FF`

Comment: Thanks, revo ! That worked for me!

Comment: Be sure to use `mb_strtolower` instead of `strtolower`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a Unicode script for Cyrillic alphabet that fortunately PHP PCRE supports it using `\p{Cyrillic}`. Besides you have to set `u` (unicode) flag to predict engine behavior. You may also need `i` flag for enabling case-insensitivity like `A-Z`:

```
~[^\p{Cyrillic}a-z0-9_\s-]~ui
```

You don't need to double escape `\s`.

PHP code:

```
preg_replace('~[^\p{Cyrillic}a-z0-9_\s-]+~ui', '', $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

To learn more about **Unicode Regular Expressions** see [this article](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html).

`\p{L}` or `\p{Letter}` matches any kind of letter from any language.

To match only Cyrillic characters, use `\p{Cyrillic}`

Since Cyrillic characters are not standard ASCII characters, you have to use `u` flag/modifier, so regex will recognize Unicode characters as needed.

Be sure to use `mb_strtolower` instead of `strtolower`, as you work with unicode characters.

Because you convert all characters to lowercase, you don't have to use `i` regex flag/modifier.

---

The following **PHP** code should work for you:

```
function seoUrl($string) {
    // Lower case everything
    $string = mb_strtolower($string);
    // Make alphanumeric (removes all other characters)
    $string = preg_replace('/[^\p{Cyrillic}a-z0-9\s_-]+/u', '', $string);
    // Clean up multiple dashes or whitespaces
    $string = preg_replace('/[\s-]+/', ' ', $string);
    // Convert whitespaces and underscore to dash
    $string = preg_replace('/[\s_]/', '-', $string);
    return $string;
}
```

---

Furthermore, please note that `\p{InCyrillic_Supplementary}` matches all [Cyrillic Supplementary characters](http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/0500-052F) and `\p{InCyrillic}` matches all [non-Supplementary Cyrillic characters](http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/0400-04FF).